# JSP End request but carry on processing

Tags: java, jsp

Is it possible to end a JSPs request by sending the response but carry on processing, implementing asynchronous processing?

I can't see a way to kick off something that the JSP container will not wait to finish?

Comment: Well, you can just launch a thread and carry on the processing you are mentioning.

Comment: yeah, in struts there is concept of execute and wait, but in jsp u need to write ur executable code in separate thread

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach would be to run a thread, preferably using a thread pool (see factory methods available in class Executors, for example ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool ).

You cold also consider "enterprise level" solutions such as Quartz. That's for more advanced requirements such as clustering, monitoring etc. We're using it through Spring (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).